# PR2 Calibration Graphs and Improvement

Tags: ros, robot-calibration, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've performed the calibration of our PR2 three times, yet it doesn't seem quite calibrated yet. I've been using [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrating%20the%%2020PR2) and recommends you view the experimental errors with `view_head_laser_scatter.sh` et al.

Here are the three graphs I get as a result.
[image: Head Laser]
[image: Head Arm]
[image: Forearm]

Two part question:

1. How should I interpret these graphs?
2. What can I do to improve the accuracy?

I can upload my cal_measurements.bag if needed. It has 75 robot_measurements in it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10873/pr2-calibration-graphs-and-improvement/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Firstly, these would be acceptable calibration charts if we were doing the calibration in-house.

The purple data points on the first graph are the error between the Prosilica camera and the head laser. Since this camera has a higher resolution, it also tends to have higher error; we generally accept values around 20-30px for that plot.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5